# Jenkins pause queue

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

**Disclaimer:**
I found out that we can pause Jenkins instance with CLI command or URL /quietDown, then resume it again.
These are steps that Jenkins already use to safely reboot the instance.
[Source](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/216118748-How-to-Start-Stop-or-Restart-your-Instance-)

And there is a [plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/PrioritySorter/) that allow me to define priorities.

TL;DR these solutions aren't complaint with the behaviour I look for

**Question:**
I would like to be able to stop/pause an active jenkins instance without losing the queue.

Example: Imagine I have one executor running one build and queue with more two builds.
I would like to manually pause the instance after the current running build is finished. And the queue will maintain as it is. Or even increasing. Then whenever I "feel like" could resume the Jenkins again and it would pick from the top of the queue.

This is attainable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, I wasn't able to find on answer on this, I tried the `/quietDown` and `/cancelQuietDown` commands.

I have found out that `/quietDown` it will pause the instance of Jenkins and does not clear the queue. In fact, the Jenkins is still working.
The queue is still receiving on demand or scheduled jobs.

After the `/cancelQuietDown`, Jenkins will start again from top of queue.

Answer (score 0):

The queue content is not persistent. It will always be lost when you stop Jenkins.

However, what you want to do is attainable in principle (if you don't mind the effort) -- you could write some groovy code that

- takes a snapshot of the queue content (before quiet-down), and which
- re-schedules those entries when Jenkins starts again.